# Sync between HDFS and NFS folders

Tags: hdfs, nfs, cloudera-cdh

How to sync the folders between NFS and HDFS without mounting the NFS on HDFS configured server.

Sync should work on vice versa too. If any files or folders deleted in HDFS should reflect on NFS system.

Please tell me the best approach or commands which I can run over the HDFS configured Linux server

Comment: Depending on the infrastructure and the goals you try to achieve you migh tbe able to use a HDFS NFS Gateway.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html 
This link may be helpful for your requirement